# Can I control my iPhone from my Mac?

Tags: iphone, mac, games, remote-control

I want to play mobile games on my Mac. How do I do that? I have been seeing a lot of iPhones controlling Macs. Where is the Mac controlling the iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it. iPhone are deisnged in a way so that you can't control them externally. Emulation is impossible, iPhone is locked from being reverse engineered. You can still emulate Android apps (many of iOS games are available on Android too) and you would not even need an Android phone. The best program for doing so is BlueStacks: http://BlueStacks.com/